# breakpoint not working on Xamarin PCL but working fine on .Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hello I have been trying to debug an Android project on mac os that was built with Xamarin Forms but have been unable to hit a single breakpoint in the Portable Class Library.

After deployment I get hollow type debugger.

[Hollow breakpoint image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0gjf.png)

But its working fine on .Android and .IOS

Here is a list of everything I have tried so far:

- Deleting the bin and obj folders then clean and rebuild Setting the
- Android build property "Link Behavior" to "Don't Link" Unselecting Strip
- native debugging symbols Removed all symbols on path to debug file
- Fresh installation of Xamarin
- fresh cloning
- changing Debug information to "Symbol only"

Can you please suggest any answer that can help me in this ?

Comment: **1)** Reboot mac. This ensures any old adb.exe is gone. **2)** In Solution Explorer, rt-click on the Xamarin PCL project, select Properties ("Options", on mac). The TargetFramework should be either .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Standard 2.1. Is it? **3)** Make a new xamarin forms solution and project. Pick any template - blank one is simplest. In Xamarin portable project, put breakpoint on App.xaml.cs, in the constructor. Run. Does it stop at breakpoint?

Comment: thank you for the reply. 
1. Reboot done still same issue.
2. Options showing .Net Standard 2.0
3. On new project Break point working fine.

Comment: Given that it works in new project, maybe easiest fix is to add your files to that new project.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was introduced in a recent visual studio update and should be fixed soon

Visual studio for **Mac**

While I wait for the new visual studio update I manage to fix this by enabling Fast Assembly Deployment located at: Android Project Options -> Android build
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Debugging-of-Xamarin-application-on-Andr/10001903

Visual studio for **Windows**

Try enabling Use Fast Deployment check this thread:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/breakpoint-not-hit-debugging-xamarin-android-proje/1561025

Answer (score -1):

According to the screenshot you provided, it seems on Windows Visual Studio.

The hollow red circle in your screenshot means disable a breakpoint without deleting it. It shows the breakpoint, but it would not work in debug.

You could click the black circle in the screenshot to enable breakpoint.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am using visual studio Mac and after deployment my breakpoint turns hollow..

Comment: breakpoint going hollow from being enabled after starting debug means that symbol (a breakpoint is called a symbol in VS save file) could not be loaded. 
When a symbol can't be loaded the debugger will not hit it.